# Reducing memory footprint of sklearn CountVectorizer, pandas and numpy

Tags: python, memory, scikit-learn

I have a Python3 software that leverage neural networks and `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer`. I have also many instances of this software (100+) and I'm having hard time understanding why every instances eats up to 190MB of RAM of which 60MB are shared.

While the neural network memory footprint is very low I can't understand why just the following statement (and other imports of **torch**, **pandas** and **numpy**) cause the software memory usage to ramp up dramatically.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
```

I've been investigating Python3 memory management, heap allocation and many other topics but as far as I can understand the above statement's side effect is to have all the symbols from `sklearn.feature_extraction.text` loaded up in memory, not only the `CountVectorizer` class and its dependencies.

First, I was tempted to think the problem was the *usage* of `CountVectorizer` so after a brief research I migrated its memory management to the classic `marisa_trie`. After many tests the memory eaten by the process was the same, so the conclusion was that the *nn* management was not the real problem.

I have finally mocked up a simple Pyton3 script with just the *import* statement (and *guppy*) to track its memory and i've found that just that statement causes the process to eats >60MB of memory.

Those are my other imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.onnx
from torch import optim
import marisa_trie
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
```

- How can be as memory-efficient as possible using those imports?
- Is it a limit of the programming language?
- Should I leverage other feature of the language to achieve my desired result?